# Rails Conditional Facebook OG Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook

I have a Rails personality test app that uses AJAX to render the questions and show the results.

I have been attempting to share personality test results via Facebook by sending the variable to one of my dashboard Rails controller to dynamically create tags.

However, the variable is nil when the page is first loaded (which causes an error), so I fixed it by adding a conditional (in application.html.erb):

```
<% if @cat %>
   <meta property="og:title"         content="You got <%= @cat.name %>!"/>
   <meta property="og:image"         content="<%= @cat.picture %>" />
   <meta property="og:description"   content="<%= @cat.description%>" />
   <meta property="og:url"           content="https://mysite" />
   <meta property="fb:app_id"        content= "<%=ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']%>" />
   <meta property="og:type"          content="website">
<% end %>
```

Facebook does not recognize the tags when I checked the sharing debugger. I also tried initializing with another object (home controller):

```
def index
  if params.has_key?("cat")
    @cat = Cat.find_by(name: params["cat"])
  else
    @cat = Cat.find_by(name: "Colonel Meow")
  end
end
```

With this, Facebook does not render the new value, but renders the old value instead. I put a debugger in my application.html to make sure the variables were changing (they did). Facebook did not refresh though.

Is there a way to use a conditional when assigning the tags? Or to refresh the tags so Facebook uses the new variable?

Comment: You should not try and change OG meta tags for the same URL constantly. Instead, provide individual URLs for each individual piece of content you want to share.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I ended up making static pages for each possible result of the personality test and made the share URL dynamic. I also used the meta-tags gem to change the tags for each page with different content.